# how to correctly initialize a LinkList

Tags: c, struct

When initializing a linked list, I define parameter as *L, like:

```
Status InitList(LinkList *L)
{ 
   *L=(LinkList)malloc(sizeof(struct LNode));
   if(!*L) 
     exit(OVERFLOW);
   (*L)->next=NULL;
   return OK;
}
```

but not

```
Status InitList(LinkList L)
{ 
   L=(LinkList)malloc(sizeof(struct LNode));
   if(!L) 
     exit(OVERFLOW);
   (L)->next=NULL;
   return OK;
}
```

Why it cannot be true?

```
struct LNode
{
    ElemType data;
    struct LNode *next;
};
typedef struct LNode *LinkList;
```

Comment: C uses call-by-value. In the second fragment, the pointer L is is passed to the function, the function assigns to it, but the caller will never see the new value. Also: hiding a ponter inside a typedef is confusing. Also2: you should not cast maloc()s return value. Also3: in `(L)->next=NULL;` the parentheses are not needed. Also4: normally people use lowercase letters for varibles and uppercase letters for preprocessor macros. Also5: your function always returns Ok, whatever that means. The other code path ends in an exit().

Comment: There's nothing wrong with having a typedef that is a pointer, but, as with any use of pointers, you need to be careful and consistent. In your code, LinkList is already a pointer to an LNode, so `LinkList *L` makes no sense. I'm assuming that the second InitList is the one that works.

Comment: @PhilPerry: no, it is the first one that works.

Comment: @littlenerd, can you confirm which version works? In the first one, L is a pointer to a pointer to an LNode. How are you making that call? The two versions appear to be otherwise similar. The difference is probably in how you make the call to InitList().

Comment: In the first one，call it with InitList(&L); in another,i call it with  InitList(L); in addition,defined LinkList L;

Comment: If the only value a function returns is OK, there is no point in returning the value; it should be a `void` function.  Then you can reduce the code that calls it by not testing the return value (because there is no value returned).  If you return an OVERFLOW status instead of using `exit(OVERFLOW);`, then you need the `Status` return type and each call should check that the return was OK.  In general, library functions should not unilaterally exit the program; they should report a failure status somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second implementation, you have a local variable `L` that you initialize.  The trouble is, it is a local variable — changing it does not change the variable in the calling code.  When the function exits, you've lost the memory that was allocated — a memory leak.  They're bad!

The first code gets a pointer to the variable in the calling code and carefully changes it.  This does not leak memory.

You can modify the second so it works by using code like this:

```
LinkList NewList(void)
{ 
   LinkList L = (LinkList)malloc(sizeof(*L));
   if (L)
   {
       L->data = 0;
       L->next = NULL;
   }
   return L;
}
```

It does a different job, so it was renamed.
Note that it ensures all elements of the structure are initialized to known values.  You'd call it like this:

```
LinkList list = NewList();
```

Comment: @littlenerd: yes, `L` is a pointer, and my code assumes that is the case.  I'm not sure what your comment is trying to tell me -- can you clarify? Personally, I would not use a pointer like `LinkList`.  I'd use `typedef struct LinkedList LinkedList;`, for example, not hiding the pointer in the `typedef`.  In my book, it is only OK to hide the pointer when you'll never dereference the type in the client code.  If your clients will dereference the type, it is kinder on them to make the pointer-ness explicit.

Comment: what do you mean about "dereference the type in the client code"?there is the concept of dereference in c? Possibly,my textbook is not good.Sorry,my English is so poor.

Comment: I mean that if you need to write `L->next` in client code, it is courteous to define `struct LNode *L;` so that it is clear that `L` is a pointer, rather than using `LinkList L;` where the fact that `L` is really a pointer is hidden.  If the only thing the client code does with `L` is pass it to functions, then there's no harm in hiding the pointer.  However, think of `FILE *`; that doesn't hide the pointer.  Dereferencing means `*ptr` or `(*ptr).Element` or `ptr->Element`; using a pointer to get at a value.

Comment: if i hide the pointer in struct. what terrible things will happen？

Comment: The main problem is that people will be misled into writing `L.next` when it needs to be `L->next`.  Because the pointer is hidden, they won't know that they need to use the pointer notation.  It's not insurmountable as a problem.  OTOH, anything that makes life easier for consumers of your software (including you in 6 months time when you've forgotten how your code works) is a good idea.  It is hard work writing good software; there's no benefit in making it harder than it need be.

Comment: thanks for your patience. may i ask you by mail and give my code later？